# How to execute custom function when data loaded in Odoo 8.x

Tags: jquery, odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

All

I hope that execute custom function when all data load is complete, I can use ajaxStop in previous versions

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
   //Do Something.
});
```

But this does not work in the new version on github.

**Is there a global method that is triggered when the data load is complete.**

Comment: What do you mean with "when the data load is complete"? Do you mean the refresh of a page or the loading of all the modules? Or perhaps something else?